# Верно ли расставлены все знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

`Потому что — хоть ставь запятую, хоть нет, — не получится сделать корректное.`

Как вы думаете?

Answer (score 1):

Неверно. Вставная конструкция *хоть ставь запятую, хоть нет* уже обособлена двумя тире.

***Потому что — хоть ставь запятую, хоть нет — не получится сделать корректно.***

---

[Знаки препинания при вставках.
§97](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85/#id-7%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85)